# tfs not showing working items in 2 screen mode

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I have a computer that is connected to 2 screens that show the same.

since 2 days ago, couple of working items are not shown. the computer was restarted, but still.

on another computer, the working items are shown.

what can be the problem?

Comment: Do the two machines connect to TFS using the same credentials?  Same URL?  Does disabling 1 screen change anything?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for the work items in a work item query.

A couple suggestions:

1-Try refreshing the query.

- With the Query Results list selected press F5 or Right-click and select **Run Query**

2- Verify the query being used *should* include the missing work items.  For example if the query being used only shows Tasks and the missing items are Risks they won't show up.

- To view the query settings Right-Click the query in the Team Explorer pane and select **View Query**

3- Try clearing the client cache.

- Delete the local cache folder: [Clear Client TFS Cache](http://blogs.msdn.com/technet/archive/2008/05/15/clear-client-tfs-cache.aspx)